# I think someone is using my WiFi

Tags: wifi

I think somebody (maybe one of my neighbors) has access to my WiFi and is using it, because even when I reset my WiFi router it gets very slow, and some of my computers seem to have their WiFi disconnected because someone else is using it.

My question is: Is there any alternative to resetting the WiFi router to "kick" that person out so they can't use my WiFi anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure you're using WPA2 with a strong password.
- Change the password.
- Use a Wifi Analyzer to make sure you're on the least crowded channel you can be.
- Disable WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup), pin can be brute forced.
- Change default router configuration login

That's all you can really do, and all you need to do.

(I do not consider MAC address filtering sufficient to help with much of anything, so don't bother)

Answer (score 0):

In you router configuration page (lots of time at 192.68.0.1 or 192.68.1.1), you probably should be able to see the MAC addresses that are currently connect to your router. things you could do on MAC address:
(1) Identify MAC address(es) that are not from your own devices. it will take some time to check all your device, laptop, phone, ipad etc
(2) Configure MAC address filtering, allow only your own devices' MAC addresses to connect to the router

Comment: Of all router based security measures, MAC address filtering is one of the least useful. Are you actually aware that anyone can change their MAC address with a single click/tap/key?

Comment: SSID/Password is a better way to go, well, people can argue there is, or will be better way to go.
Regarding the MAC address filtering, i totally agree MAC iis easy to modify to against blacklist, though one of my points here is that a MAC whitelist is still a good use case here, since it's hard(not totally impossible) to guess which MAC address(es) in the whitelist of the router

Comment: `"it's hard(not totally impossible) to guess which MAC address(es) in the whitelist of the router"` No, really, it's very easy. You just put your wireless network card in monitor mode and wait until an authorized client sends any packet over the network (often a matter of mere seconds). That whitelisted address is all you need (unless the wireless network is encrypted, but then you would of course have even less reason to use MAC address filtering in the first place).

Comment: Point taken. Thinking it practically brings one question that when my MAC address (MAC1) is already in use on my network with IP1, if my neighbor forces his own device (with IP2) to change from say, MAC2, to my in-use MAC address MAC1, the behavior of the network following that event will somehow depend on the implementation of the router, one is that some routers/NAT implement MAC-IP mapping, will be allow multiple IPs to one MAC mapping, etc. Well, anyway, it's already a fact that my neighbor has been able to mess up with my network to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your router's brand, another thing to consider is the SSID. For example, Thomson and Speedtouch modems broadcast a default SSID such as "ThomsonXXXXXX" where the last six X-es are required to calculate the default password.

As mentioned by gowenfawr earlier it is recommended to change the password and also consider changing the SSID since clients try to automatically re-connect to an existing SSID.